# Dropbox API (Core & Drop-in) issue No Peer certificate

Tags: android, dropbox-api

i try to make a simple app with dropbox api,
the first thing i do is connect a dbxchooser

```
mChooser=new DbxChooser(APP_KEY_DBX);
```

after that i connect the dropbox object;

```
appKeys= new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET);
AndroidAuthSession session= new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
mDBApi= new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this);
```

when i try to get the file choosed with the Dbxchooser

```
DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
dl_file asyncDownload = new dl_file(MainActivity.this, mDBApi, result, file);
asyncDownload.execute();
```

---

```
String cachePath= mContex.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ file.getName();
try
{
    outputStream= new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
    DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile(result.getLink().toString(), null, outputStream, null);
    Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev);
    Toast.makeText(mContex, "download terminato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (DropboxServerException e) {
```

....

aferter several time i receive the error:

> com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxSSLException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException:No Peer certificate

and the app don't download anything, can someone help me?

Comment: This error means the app receives a wrong TLS certificate for the HTTPS connection. Are you on a captive WiFi portal, like in a hotel? Try going to the Dropbox website in a normal browser on the device, do you get a certificate warning?

Comment: i use my home wi-fi, i test the official dropbox app and that works well, is it possibile the connection of the DbxChooser and the DropboxAPI create some conflict?

Comment: This error can also occur if there are time-out issues, which occurred during debugging in my case.

Comment: Hi @giovannibernabei, did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same problem.